# Trying to use BufferedReader to read input from System.in and put it into an array, however doesn't seem to want to give me the array

Tags: java, arrays, input, bufferedreader

As stated in the title, I am using a BufferedReader that reads from System.in and puts the values into an array of Strings. When I call the method to do this, I try to check the length of the array, but nothing gets printed out when I do so.

```
String s = "";
        BufferedReader io = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(System.in));     //create a new BufferedReader using system input

        String line;                                    //will be changed to the next line in the input
        try                                             //required or we cant compile it because exceptions
        {
            s = io.readLine() + "_";    //get the first integer value, which is how many 
                                                        //  pieces of info we have to process
            while((line = io.readLine()) != null)       //read until the end of the file
            {   
                s += io.readLine() + "_";                       //add it to the ArrayList (may not be needed)
                //System.out.println("Added line to list");
                //System.out.println(line);
            }

            io.close();                                 //done with input, close the stream
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return s.split("_");
```

I then call the method containing this code, but literally nothing is printed out:

```
 String[] input = readInput();


    System.out.println(input.length);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling readLine() twice inside your loop and throwing every odd result away. You need to assign the result obtained in the while condition and use that inside the loop, instead of calling it again.